# ActiveAdmin & Devise -- reset_password_token is not unique when updating Users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

So I have Devise on the backend running authorization for an `Active` model (you can think of Actives as Users). I also have ActiveAdmin running in conjunction with this.

Here's `app/admin/active.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Active do

  # Specify which columns we want to appear in our ActiveAdmin index page
  index do
    column :name
    column :email
    column :class
    column :major

    # Adds view/edit/delete actions
    default_actions
  end

  controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit!
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the problem: Say I populate my database with 100 Actives. I then go into ActiveAdmin to try to edit an Active, and there's a bunch of fields, including something called `Reset password token`. The problem is, there is a uniqueness constraint on the `Reset password token` (by Devise), as I need to input something different in its field for each Active that I edit. For instance, if I leave it blank when editing the first Active, the update goes through. If I leave the field blank *again* when editing a second Active, I get this error:

`SQLite3::ConstraintException: column reset_password_token is not unique: UPDATE "actives" SET "encrypted_password" = ?, "reset_password_token" = ?, "current_sign_in_ip" = ?, "last_sign_in_ip" = ?, "major" = ?, "class" = ?, "biography" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "actives"."id" = 95`

My question: what is the best way to handle this? From what I know (which isn't much) the `Reset password token` is used if the user forgets their password and it needs to be sent to them, so what should an administrator put in this field if they need to update the user? What is the best fix in this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to change the reset password token? If you can i would suggest not even make an admin have the ability to change that field since the system takes care of it. Dont send the reset password token field from your view so an admin cant change it.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Do I just remove the field from the view? Wouldn't this just submit each `update` request with a blank `Reset password token`?

Comment: No by removing just the form field rails wont change that field, it will just leave it as it is.

Comment: Are you using files Devise created for the admins to edit an active or are you using code written by yourself in the view? Can you add the view you are using for admins to edit an active?

Comment: I'm using the files Devise created for the admins to edit an active; how do I access this and get rid of the `Reset password token` from the ActiveAdmin edit view?

Answer (score 0):

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Run this command and you will be able to customize Devise views.

You can read more about editing devise views here
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views

Comment: But this just generates the views that `Devise` creates, not the ones in the Admin interface, right?

Comment: I thought you where using the files Devise created for you to edit an active, if you genereate the views you can look at them and change them to fit your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, and I am able to successfully edit actives in my Devise-generated edit page. However, the problem is when I try to edit an Active in the `ActiveAdmin` portal -- then the `Reset password token` problem appears.

Answer (score 0):

Write NULL into rerset_password instead of blank.

If you set blank for first user, then second blank became subject of constraint.

In case of unique constraint NULL allowed to be repeated and do not considered to be same value. But note, that not all engines confirm this standard. For example MS SQL Server does not and you will need add condition into constraint, like *where: '([reset_password_token] IS NOT NULL)'*

Answer (score 0):

A pity that there is no correct answer here for the actual question. I faced the exact same issue and came here to no avail. Now, after reading `Active Admin` docs and `formatastic` docs, I have managed to solve the issue.

**Solution:**

The issue is that the `reset_password_token` is automatically added to the Active Admin forms and it is `null`, by default. If we simply go through with this then we get away with one submission but not after that because database requires unique entries and only one `null` is allowed. The only viable way is to keep giving unique `reset_password_token` manually when submitting the form, every time, but that is not practical.

Active Admin provides a way to control the form fields, though. You need to add this to your above file:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Active do

  # Specify which columns we want to appear in our Active Admin form (new and edit):
  form title: 'Form for active ([...or any title you want...])' do |f|
    inputs 'Details' do
      input :name
      input :email
      input :class
      input :major
      # add any other fields you want to allow
      # but not adding other fields means no other field will come into the form
      # including reset_password_token. Hence, problem solved :-)
    end
    actions
  end
  
  # Rest of your code goes here...
end
```

For more about available input options and usage of the form, here is formatastic documentation: https://github.com/formtastic/formtastic

(Check the end of **Usage** section and **The Available Inputs**)

Comment: @r123454321 please accept the answer as it is the correct solution. I hope it helps someone :)